# use import_module to access module from site-packages

Tags: python, windows, modulenotfounderror, python-importlib, site-packages

I want to import all modules from a particular directory of a package which I installed using pip, that is, it lies in `site-packages`.

**What I tried**

Let's say the package name is `package` and it has a directory called `directory`. It has many files like `a.py`, `b.py`, etc. I need to import all of them. I listed all files in `directory` using in-built `__file__`, which isn't the problem. When I tried to import the modules using `importlib.import_module`, I got `ModuleNotFoundError` even though I'm 100% percent sure they exist. I used relative import.

**Code Snippet**

`modules` is the list of all files in `directory`

```
for module in modules:
    importlib.import_module('.'+module, 'C:\\Users\\.....\\package\\directory')
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\.....\\package\\directory'`

**Finally**

What am I doing wrong and what is the right approach to refer site-packages?

Answer (score 0):

create an empty `__init__.py` file under the directory that you want to
execute

```
import pkgutil
import sys


def load_all_modules_from_dir(dirname):
    for importer, package_name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([dirname]):
        full_package_name = '%s.%s' % (dirname, package_name)
        if full_package_name not in sys.modules:
            module = importer.find_module(package_name
                        ).load_module(full_package_name)
            print module


load_all_modules_from_dir('site-packages')
```

Comment: This code will only work if run in parent directory of `site-packages` which defeats the whole purpose.
Also, I would need path to directory not site-packages
But even if I get the absolute path to `site-packages` or `directory` it gives import error